# Linq to XML Descendants can't read part of xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have XML document like this

```
<document>
    <indexroot>
        <type>type</type>
        <model>model</model>
    </indexroot>
    <root>
        <model_type1>model type 1</model_type1>
        <model_type2>model type 2</model_type2>
    </root>
</document>
```

And a linq to xml code:

```
var elements = (from element in pdb.Descendants()
                select new
                {
                    type = (string)element.Element("type") ?? "-",
                    model= (string)element.Element("model") ?? "-",
                    model_type1= (string)element.Element("model_type1") ?? "-",
                    model_type2= (string)element.Element("model_type2") ?? "-"
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get type and a model variables, but it seems I can't reach model_type1 and model_type2, now I understand that this happens because indexroot and root tags, amd if I seperate those tags into diffrent linq to xml code blocks with Descendants("indexroot") and Descendants("root"), everything works fine, but I wan't them in one block, is it possible to achieve that, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate down the XML heirarchy for each element you are trying to extract.

This is because the Element method only looks at direct children, not all descendants of a node. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets the first (in document order) child element with the specified XName.

One implementation using just Linq-to-XML might be:

```
 xml = "<document>" +
    "<indexroot>" +
    "    <type>type</type>" +
    "    <model>model</model>" +
    "</indexroot>" +
    "<root>" +
    "    <model_type1>model type 1</model_type1>" +
    "    <model_type2>model type 2</model_type2>" +
    "</root>" +
    "</document>";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var newItem = (from element in doc.Descendants("document")
                select new 
    {
        Type = (string)element.Element("indexroot").Element("type") ?? "-",
        Model = (string)element.Element("indexroot").Element("model") ?? "-",
        ModelType1 = (string)element.Element("root").Element("model_type1") ?? "-",
        ModelType2 = (string)element.Element("root").Element("model_type2") ?? "-",
    }).FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine(newItem);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, just one question if I may, is there a way to achieve same but using "XElement" instead of "XDocument"?

Comment: The code would work exactly the same with an XElement as an XDocument :)

Comment: I see, it's intresting how it works, when I use XDocument the condition Type = (string)element.Element("indexroot").Element("type") ?? "-" works fine if say sometimes element "type" doesn't exists in xml document, and when that happens with XElement it throws error.